# Neo4J: Return latest data node for each value of a given key

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a dataset in Neo4J that gets updated regularly, and I want to write a single query that will get me the latest data node for each value of a given key in the database, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's an example of how my data looks (simplified):

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 3 days ago>",
    "component": "a",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 1 day ago>",
    "component": "a",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 6 days ago>",
    "component": "b",
    "value": "5"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 4 days ago>",
    "component": "b",
    "value": "9"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 2 days ago>",
    "component": "b",
    "value": "11"
  },
  ...
}
```

From this example data, I would want to return one row for each unique `component`, and it would be the most recent based on the timestamp:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 1 day ago>",
    "component": "a",
    "value": "2"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "<timestamp - 2 days ago>",
    "component": "b",
    "value": "11"
  },
  ...
]
```

Or if I just return specific columns that I care about:

```
| component | value |
| ---       | ---   |
| a         | 2     |
| b         | 11    |
| ...       | ...   |
```

Is there a good, concise way of doing this with cypher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you put your data in a parameter, you could do

```
// back to rows
UNWIND $data AS row

// order by timestamp
WITH row.component AS component,
     row.timestamp AS timestamp,
     row.value AS value
ORDER BY timestamp DESC

// get first item in the sorted collection
WITH component,
     COLLECT({timestamp:timestamp,value:value})[0] AS tsval

// construct the array
RETURN COLLECT({timestamp:tsval.timestamp,component:component,value:tsval.value}) AS result
```

or just

```
RETURN component,tsval.value AS value
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is passed to the query as the `data` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), this query uses [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT`:

```
UNWIND $data AS d
WITH d
ORDER BY d.timestamp DESC
RETURN d.component AS component, COLLECT(d.value)[0] AS value
```

to produce a result that looks like this:

```
╒═══════════╤═══════╕
│"component"│"value"│
╞═══════════╪═══════╡
│"b"        │"11"   │
├───────────┼───────┤
│"a"        │"2"    │
└───────────┴───────┘
```